# How do i find the derivative dy/dx of given curve. (y is fn of x)

Tags: calculus, differential

the curve is $\dfrac{x+\sqrt{(a^2-y^2)}}{a}$ = $\log\dfrac{(a+\sqrt{(a^2+y^2)}}{y}$ i need to find the length of tangent for which i need to evaluate slope $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$. please help

Comment: OK, what's stopping you?  How far have you gotten?  Also, tangent lines are usually infinitely long.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate implicitly the given equation:

$$\frac1adx-\frac{y}{a\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}dy=\frac y{a+\sqrt{a^2+y^2}}\cdot\frac{\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{a^2+y^2}}-a-\sqrt{a^2+y^2}}{y^2}dy\iff$$

$$\color{red}{\frac1adx-\frac{y}{a\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}dy}=\frac y{a+\sqrt{a^2+y^2}}\cdot\frac{-a\sqrt{a^2+y^2}-a^2}{y^2}dy=\color{red}{-\frac ay dy}$$

and now do $\;\cfrac{dy}{dx}\;$ and solve...

Comment: Should $\frac12 dx$ be $\frac{1}{a} dx$?

Comment: @TonyK Indeed so, thanks. Good catch.

Comment: Actually question says the length of tangent to this curve will be a constant  equal to $a$. after getting the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ from your solution when i put it in formulla length of tangent = $y\sqrt{1+\frac{dx}{dy}^2}$ i m not getting $a$ plz help.

Comment: sorry it is $\frac{dx}{dy}$ whole square